# How can I link to the author's page

Tags: permalinks, users

Hi) I have a question about this code:

```
 <?php
   $args = array(
    'role' => 'contributor',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'number'  => 3
  );
   $users = get_users($args);
    echo '<div class="col-md-12" style="background-color:#d8d8d8;">';
     foreach ($users as $user) {
      echo '<a href="">' . $user->display_name.'['.$user->user_email . ']('.$user->id . ') </div></a>' ;
     }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

I must insert a link that allows to go to  the author page. I must insert a link that allows to go to  the author page. Thanks.

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem, do not include the word WordPress.

Comment: <a href=".get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ).">user post url</a>

Answer (score 1):

I depends on whether you want the URL to the authors posts:

```
'<a href="'.get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ).'">user posts url</a>'
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url

Or the url to edit the user:

```
'<a href="'.get_edit_user_link( $user->ID ).'">edit user url</a>'
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_edit_user_link